# Order by Hibernate Criteria API One to Many Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to order a query using hibernate criteria API. My object model is as follows Object A has a One to Many with Object B.
I am trying to order as follows whilst paging

```
B.f1
A.field1
A.field2
```

So the mapping in Object B which I have created the criteria for is

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_name", nullable = false)
    public A getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
```

I creat a criteria api for object B

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class);
```

I then add some Restrictions to this critera and create a Criteria for Object A as well and add the order by clauses for Object A.

```
//add some restrictions for object B
Criteria aCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("A");
//Criteria aCriteria = criteria.createAlias("A", "a");
processaFilters(aCriteria, filters);
aCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("field1"));
aCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("field2"));
```

Then I add the order by criteria for object B

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
        Long rowCount = (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();

        criteria.setProjection(null);
        criteria.setFirstResult(offset!=null ? offset : 0);
        criteria.setMaxResults(maxResult!=null ? maxResult : 10);
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("f1"));

        List<B> bList = criteria.list();
```

However this does not order in the correct way. I have read about alias and tried it but was not sure how to implement it. There is nothing wrong with my criteria query as it works fine and only after I implemeted paging have I needed to add the ordering
Any pointers?
Thanks

UPDATE:

I tried creating an Alias by doing the following:

```
criteria.createAlias("A", "c");
processClaimantFilters(criteria, filters);
```

and in the method 
    processaFilters(aCriteria, filters);

I changed all the properties to use c for example

```
if (filters.getind() != null) {
            aCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.ind",   filters.getInd()));
    }
```

I removed the order by stuff just to see if it would work but when I call

```
List<B> bList = criteria.list();
```

The return result is not an object of type B but rather an List of Object [] which contains objects A and B. So I guess I am no using the alias correctly